# Error de sintaxis en python

Tags: python, numpy

escribí este código en Python. Cuando estoy ejecutando esto, en la consola dice que tengo un error en la línea 19 que es la línea debajo del bloque try except. El error es una sintaxis no válida, pero no entiendo por qué está mal

Quiero poner en una lista vacía la función llamada puntual o puntual 2 que tomará un valor i de un bucle que declararé debajo de todo eso.

Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y no sé si el código que escribí está bien

```
def puntual(num1,num2):
   carga = num1*(i-num2)
   return carga
   
def puntual2(num1,num2):
   carga2 = (num1*2)*(i-num2)
   return carga2

listavacia = []

for x in range(100):
   
   try : anadircargas = int(input('¿Añadir Carga? Pulse 1'))    
       
   if anadircargas == 1:
       
       anadir_cargas2 = int(input("¿Añadir Carga puntual? Pulse 1"))
       
       if anadir_cargas2 ==1:
               
           numero1 = int(input("Dame la carga"))
           numero2 = int(input("Dame la distancia"))
               
           listavacia.append(puntual(numero1,numero2))
               
       else:
               
           numero1 = int(input("Dame la carga distribuida"))
           numero2 = int(input("Dame la distancia"))
               
           listavacia.append(puntual2(numero1,numero2))
   else:
       
       print("Gracias por usar el programa")
       break
       
   except:
       pass
```

Comment: El código está bien identado?

Comment: el problema es la identacion, ya probé el código y funciona correctamente, si lo identas bien

Comment: Lo de 'correctamente' es relativo @Christian, jejeje. Hay un error oculto que le puesto en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Es curioso. En tu pregunta el código se ve correctamente sangrado, pero al hacer copy-paste al IDE, resulta esto:

```
else:

    print("Gracias por usar el programa")
    break

except:
pass
```

El detalle es que `pass` quedar sangrado respecto a `except:

```
else:

    print("Gracias por usar el programa")
    break

except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias cosas en tu código:

1. En primer lugar `anadircargas` debería ir en la línea siguiente al
   `try` y con su indentación correspondiente.
2. el `if` a continuación del `try` tampoco esta indentado
   correctamente, ya que está al mismo nivel que el `try`.
3. En las funciones `puntual1` y `puntual2` tienes una variable `i` no
   declarada que te va a dar un error (que no vas a detectar) y que te
   explico más abajo.

**Problemas 1 y 2**

El código con las indentaciones corregidas quedaría así, pero ya te aviso que aún no te va a funcionar:

```
def puntual(num1, num2):
   carga = num1 * (i - num2)
   return carga
   
def puntual2(num1 , num2):
   carga2 = (num1 * 2) * (i - num2)
   return carga2

listavacia = []

for x in range(100):
    try:
        anadircargas = int(input('¿Añadir Carga? Pulse 1'))

        if anadircargas == 1:
            anadir_cargas2 = int(input("¿Añadir Carga puntual? Pulse 1"))

            if anadir_cargas2 == 1:
                numero1 = int(input("Dame la carga"))
                numero2 = int(input("Dame la distancia"))
                listavacia.append(puntual(numero1, numero2))

            else:
                numero1 = int(input("Dame la carga distribuida"))
                numero2 = int(input("Dame la distancia"))
                listavacia.append(puntual2(numero1, numero2))

        else:
            print("Gracias por usar el programa")
            break

    except:
        pass
```

**Problema 3**

Con esto tu código se ejecuta, te pide lo que quieres y parece que todo funciona correcto, pero no es así.

Como ya te he dicho, al tener una variable no declarada en las funciones te van a dar un error al intentar ejecutarse, pero no se ve ya que tienes puesto un:

```
except:
    pass
```

Que es la peor combinación que podías haber puesto, ya que el `except` te capturará cualquier error que pueda haber (es mejor especificar el error exacto que esperas que pueda darse) y el `pass` hará que ni siquiera se te avise de que hay un error. Prueba a cambiar esas líneas por estas líneas y verás lo que pasa al ejecutar:

```
except:
    print('Aquí hay un error que no había visto')
    pass
```

Deberías asignarle un valor a `i` en las funciones y al menos (lo mínimo) que el `except` te avise si se ejecuta.

**Posible mejora**

Sospecho que al poner `for x in range(100)` lo que pretendías hacer era tener un número alto de `inputs` para meter datos pero que el usuario no utilice todos y se abandone el bucle antes de llegar a los 100.

Si ese es el caso, puedes utilizar mejor un `while`, que se ejecuta hasta que se deja de cumplir la condición que le digas:

```
while input('¿Añadir Carga? Pulse 1') == '1':
    try:
        anadir_cargas2 = int(input("¿Añadir Carga puntual? Pulse 1"))

        if anadir_cargas2 == 1:
            numero1 = int(input("Dame la carga"))
            numero2 = int(input("Dame la distancia"))
            listavacia.append(puntual(numero1, numero2))
        else:
            numero1 = int(input("Dame la carga distribuida"))
            numero2 = int(input("Dame la distancia"))
            listavacia.append(puntual2(numero1, numero2))
          
    except:
        pass  # Esto cámbialo cuanto antes

print("Gracias por usar el programa")
```

Comment: pusiste un parentesis de mas en el ciclo `while` >_<

Comment: Cierto @Christian, muchas gracias!!

Comment: una respuesta con *error de sintaxis*  en una pregunta de *error de sintaxis*  °-°